# Jquery variable output is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery code:

```
var notifications = $('.alerts').text();
document.title = '(' + notifications + ') ' + document.title;
```

the html is like this:

```
<span class="alerts">1</span>
```

(where 1 is a dynamic number).

Obviously I am doing something wrong, because the title shows:

**() Some Title**

I tried  alert(notifications);

and it shows an empty output.

Comment: spans don't use the `text` method do they? Try `innerHTML" instead.

Comment: Try replacing `.text()` with `.html()`

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @Carcigenicate - Yes, spans can use `.text()`

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui Why would that make any difference if the content is just text?

Comment: This fiddle works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/fv9oyjay/

Comment: cannot reproduce :(

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried replacing text() with html() and now the output is (undefined)

Comment: @kblok I saw your fiddle and indeed it works. I guess there is some kind of conflict.

Comment: @j08691 the developer console says everything is fine :(

Comment: Maybe you are loading the javascript code before the dynamic span value changes. add this line to your code setTimeout(function(){alert($('.alerts').text())}, 3000); To check if it is a load order error

Comment: @AlfredoEM YES... now it outputs the number.. how can I make the script execute later?

Comment: @AlfredoEM I did it like this:



setTimeout( function(){

    
    /* notifications in page title */

var notifications = $('.alerts').text();
document.title = '(' + notifications + ') ' + document.title; 

}, 1000); // delay 1000 ms


Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: That is not the better way, try this please, Put your <script>// all code </script> just before the end of the </body> close tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is using javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="alerts">1</span>
  <script>
    var notifications = $('.alerts').text();
    document.title = '(' + notifications + ') ' + document.title; 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this. It is using Jquery.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var notifications = $('.alerts').text();
     document.title = '(' + notifications + ') ' + document.title; 
    });
   </script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <span class="alerts">1</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is very simple. if we write the <script/> in <head> then it will execute first.
after executing the <head> the <body> will renders. 
and if we write <script> in <body> then it will execute when the body of the page renders.

Answer (score -1):

It was a load order error as pointed out by AlfredoEM.

I resolved it by adding a timeout for the function:

```
setTimeout( function(){


    /* notifications in page title */

var notifications = $('.alerts').text();
document.title = '(' + notifications + ') ' + document.title; 

}, 1000); // delay 1000 ms
```

Comment: That is not the better way, please try this: wrap your code with $( document ).ready(function() {
    // all code here (without setTimeout)
}); and Put your <script>// all code </script> just before the end of the </body> close tag, to ensure that javascript loads after html

Comment: Yes, @AlfredoEM is right. This is wrong way. Because after one second it will executes